# Fetch pages with scrapy behind Google Authentication

Tags: scrapy, google-authentication

I'm trying to log into a website that uses Google credentials. This fails in my scrapy spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'email': self.var.user, 'password': self.var.password},
        callback=self.after_login)
```

Any tips?

Comment: If you can post the whole source code and what's the error?

Comment: I managed to solve it, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

After further inspection I managed to solve this, seems to be, a simple issue:

1. The fields are `Email` and `Passwd`, in that order.
2. Break the log in into two request, the first for email, second for password.

The code that works, as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
    """
    Insert the email. Next, go to the password page.
    """
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'Email': self.var.user},
        callback=self.log_password)


def log_password(self, response):
    """
    Enter the password to complete the log in.
    """
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'Passwd': self.var.password},
        callback=self.after_login)
```