# Google Authentication with Python / Scrapy

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

## Problem Summary

I am attempting to log in to Google (at this non-JS URL: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?nojavascript=1) and am running into issues. I referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381055/fetch-pages-with-scrapy-behind-google-authentication), as it seems closely related, but the 302 redirect that occurs when debugging manually via Chrome dev tools does not execute in Scrapy. Instead, Scrapy follows a 200 status code and heads to the request URL (https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password).

You can see in the attached photo that there are two separate POSTs – one for "lookup" (which is the email address) and one for password. The password redirects to the "success" page if you log in successfully, and will follow the request URL if the login is unsuccessful.

Additionally, I have tried providing both "Email" and "Passwd" for the second POST, and it fails the same way as it does with just "Passwd". I am at a loss for what else to try.

[image: Google Login POSTs]

## My Code

```
def parse(self, response):

        # Log in to Google 
        sanitized = False
        while not sanitized:
            prompt_controller("Enter your email:")
            email = input()

            if (email == "" or email is None):
                sanitized = False
            else:
                sanitized = True

        return FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                         formdata = {"Email": email},
                                         callback = self.password_login)

def password_login(self, response):

        """
        Handles second POST for Google authentication.
        """

        sanitized = False
        while not sanitized:
            prompt_controller("Enter your password:")
            password = input()

            if (password == "" or password is None):
                sanitized = False
            else:
                sanitized = True

        return FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                         formdata = {"Passwd": password},
                                         callback = self.after_login)
```

## Thoughts

I am certain one of two things is happening.

One, the login is failing for some reason, so the 200 code makes sense and it is following the request URL. If this is the case, why is the login failing?

Two, the login is actually succeeding, but Scrapy is ignoring the 302 redirect and following the request URL, which in this case happens to be the failed login page.

Thanks a ton for your help! It's very much appreciated.